# Mostrar una vista parcial, con la función onClick, desde un grid ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

En una de mis vistas parciales llamada `_SAMISyncDataPartial.cshtml` implemento un gridView que en su configuración tiene un `settings.ClientSideEvents.RowClick = "OnClick";`

en otra de mis vistas parciales llamada `_OptionWizard.cshtml`tengo varias imágenes a mostrar.

Estás dos vistas parciales se llaman desde mi vista principal `SAMISync.cshtml`
en la vista principal tengo la función

```
function OnClick()
{

    alert("entro");
}
```

`

**problema:** con solo dar click en algún lugar del grid se me debe abrir las imágenes sin recargar la página, tengo entendido que lo puedo hacer por medio de la función onclick, creo que soy específico.

*para mayor soporte dejo imágenes del funcionamiento*

al dar click en cualquier lugar del grid, se debe cargar lo siguiente...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto hacerlo con ajax para que no recargue la imagen.

espero tener ayuda y haber sido claro con mi pregunta, gracias. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Eese gridview es nativo o estas usando algun complemento como devexpress?

Comment: Puedes compartir el código de **AJAX** y los controladores?